angular pwa returning 504 even thought it can work offline properly
I have an Angular application with @angular/pwa
here is the ngsw-config.json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "navigationRequestStrategy": "freshness",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/**/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": ["/api"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 1000,
        "maxAge": "30d"
      }
    }
  ]
}

how if I lost connection and I return to the pages I was using all is good and working
but the problem is when I refresh I get 504 and I don't understand why since the pages can work offline properly if I don't refresh, this happen to both pages requiring api call and static pages, I have SSR enabled in the project and these static pages are prerendered
